# Adding a Range of Dates in a View grouped by Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, view

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to set a range of dates (-1 week, current week, +1 week; 3 weeks in total) based on the current date to a column in a view. The idea is to put the range to the view even though there are no corresponding values in the view.

Example values:

```
Current date: 2020-02-01
First day one week back: 2020-01-25
Last day one week forward: 2020-02-12
```

Where I come from:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 [to be grouped] | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | EFGH | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | IJKL | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | MNOP | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | QRST | NULL |

Where I want to go:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 [to be grouped] | Dates | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-01-25 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-01-26 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-01-27 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-01-28 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-01-29 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-01 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-02 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-03 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-04 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-05 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-08 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-09 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-10 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-11 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | ABCD | 2020-02-12 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | EFGH | 2020-01-25 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| AAAAA | 1001 | EFGH | 2020-02-12 | NULL |
| AAAAA | 1001 | IJKL | 2020-01-25 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| AAAAA | 1001 | IJKL | 2020-02-12 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

So even though there are no values, I'd like to show the dates anyway. The view is supposed to be a ready to use pattern for data input.

Edit:
What I tried so far is, to work with `DATEADD()` and defining the desired ranges. I get the output I desire as a single select statement but fail to add that up to the query. A join with the calendar is not possible due to missing values, as well as an union. What I basically miss is something like an iteration e.g. loop, but that's bad style in manner of SQL.

The view so far, as I don't know how to solve the desired state of the date values:

```
CREATE view vDateAdd as 
with val as
select x.* from (
select *, row_number() over (
partition by Column 2, Dates order by Dates desc
) #row from sourcetable1) val
where a.#row = 1 )
) select Y.* from (
select 
sourcetable2.Column1, 
sourcetable2.Column2, 
sourcetable2.Column3, 
sourcetable3.Values 
from sourcetable2 
left join sourcetable3 
sourcetable2.Column3 on sourcetable3.Column3 
where Column2 IS NOT NULL
)Y
```

Comment: @DaleK added some info. I'm quite lost, that's why I'm here.

Comment: In that case a tutorial might be more appropriate, to build up your knowledge.

Comment: In that case maybe I should delete the question since there will be no value for those having the same question in future

Comment: You said you tried a join with a calendar table, so show us that, you've probably just joined in the wrong order, because calendar tables are how you solve the issue of gaps in the data.

Comment: @DaleK I added the view definition. Yes, I *tried* to join the calendar table, but with what is the question? Since there is nothing to join on, I believe there is some simple solution to that but I don't know how

Comment: But thats not even valid SQL? And If you want to make life easy for those trying to assist you, provide the sample data as DDM+DML (i.e. create temp table, insert into temp table). And iron out any syntax errors before posting.

Comment: And when you say nothing to join to, thats where a `CROSS JOIN` comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a number or tally table for this.  There are a lot of ways to create this sort of table and populate it, please Google that or search for it on Stack Exchange.  After you have a table that has a row for numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6...10000 or so. You can use that table here (it is called dbo.Numbers in the query below):

```
create table #weeks
(
    Column1 varchar(10),
    Column2 varchar(10),
    Column3 varchar(10)
)
insert into #weeks
select 'AAAAA','10001','abcd'
union all
select 'AAAAA','10001','efgh'
union all
select 'AAAAA','10001','ijkl'
union all
select 'AAAAA','10001','mnop'
union all
select 'AAAAA','10001','qrst' 

select 
    Column1, 
    Column2, 
    Column3, 
    case when n.Number > 21 --going into the fuuttuuureee... so return it to 1-21
        then dateadd(day,42-n.Number,getdate()) 
        else dateadd(day,-1*n.Number, getdate()) --going into the past, using 1-21, just go negative here so *-1
        end as DateColumn
from #weeks
cross join dbo.NUMBERS n
where 
    n.Number <= 42 --6 weeks total, 3 back, 3 forward 6*7 = 42
order by Column3, DateColumn
```

Comment: You could just do `dateadd(day,n.Number - 21,getdate())`. Also, see [Itzik Ben-Gan's tally tables](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1)

Comment: @Charlieface @Jesse Thanks for your answers! So what I did now is a cross join on my calendar table and `WHERE cDate >= DATEADD(wk, -2, GETDATE()) and cDate <= DATEADD(wk, 2, GETDATE())`